# Environment variables Mac OS Sierra location

Tags: macos, sh, bash

I'm trying to set global environment variables in my mac so that they can be seen from anywhere. I've tried setting them in both `/profile` and `/.bash_profile` but still when I run my script from blender then call echo `$MY_LIB_PATH` and echo `$MY_PRO_PATH` only one of them `$My_PRO_PATH` exists, I'm not sure why, looks like there is another location where `$My_PRO_PATH` is set where I need to set `$My_LIB_PATH` as well. Any advice please?

this is my /etc/profile:

```
# System-wide .profile for sh(1)

if [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then
    eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
fi

if [ "${BASH-no}" != "no" ]; then
    [ -r /etc/bashrc ] && . /etc/bashrc
fi

export MY_LIB_PATH=/usr/local/mypro/mylib/
export MY_PRO_PATH=/usr/local/mypro/
```

this is my bash_profile:

```
export MY_LIB_PATH=/usr/local/mypro/mylib/
export MY_PRO_PATH=/usr/local/mypro/
```

Comment: Where/how did you run your script? From within the macOS's *Terminal* App?

Comment: `/profile` is not a location.  If you look at the `path_helper` man page, it actually tells you where you can customize these settings.

Comment: You should not use the Bash-only `export VAR=value` syntax in a script which is also executed by `sh`.  The portable syntax is `VAR=value; export VAR`.

Comment: Uppercase variable names are reserved for system use.  You should use lowercase variables if you are in control over this.

Comment: @tripleee thanks for your comments. When I run my script in terminal using `~/Desktop/./run-test.sh` which has two lines ` echo $MY_LIB_PATH` and `echo $MY_PRO_PATH ` they are both printed. For some reason when I run my shell script from blender using `os.system('~/Desktop/./run-test.sh')` which has two lines ` echo $MY_LIB_PATH` and `echo $MY_PRO_PATH ` only `My_PRO_PATH ` is printed. Any thoughts please?

Comment: Did you reboot your system after changing `/etc/profile` if indeed you did change that?

Comment: @tripleee which system? you mean reboot my mac? I didn't reboot my mac, I closed/terminated terminal and reopened it and when I type `echo $MY_LIB_PATH` and `echo $MY_PRO_PATH` they are both printed in the terminal. But for some reason calling the script from blender only print one of them which makes me think that possible I need to add the `MY_LIB_PATH ` somewhere else. Now they are both in etc/profile and bash_profile as shown in the question like that:
`export MY_LIB_PATH=/usr/local/mypro/mylib/`
`export MY_PRO_PATH=/usr/local/mypro/`

Comment: `/etc/profile` only gets evaluated system-wide at system startup.

Comment: @tripleee okay, I'll try. Although I didn't do a restart before and one of them is already printed when calling echo :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139326/discussion-between-tak-and-tripleee).

Comment: @tripleee I tried making a .command file called mytest.command which has 2 echos for the two variables but when I run it only one of them is printed although if I terminated all terminal sessions and opened new one then typed echo for both in it they are both displayed?